# Can a group (infinite order) have elements of finite order and infinite order simultaneously

Tags: group-theory

I know examples of groups of infinite order where all the elements are of finite order. But I am not sure about this question

Comment: Try $\mathbb Q^*$. Or $\mathbb C^*$ if you want infinitely many examples of both finite and infinite order.

Comment: What are the examples you know of groups of infinite order where all the elements are of finite order? Depending what they are, it may be easy to alter them to give you examples of the groups you are after.

Comment: You certainly know about the group $GL_n(K)$ from linear algebra. Now, certain matrices have infinite order, others not, right? What about $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  For instance, you could go with a finitely generated abelian group with both a torsion part and a free part.  So, anything like, $\Bbb Z^n×\Bbb Z_{p_1^{n_1}}×\dots×\Bbb Z_{p_k^{n_k}}$.

Or try the circle group, $\Bbb T=\{z:|z|=1\}$.  The torsion elements being the $n$-th roots of unity, the remaining elements having infinite order.

There are other examples, finitely generated or not, abelian or not.  You could write down a presentation for such a group fairly easily, i would think.  Here's one $\langle a,b|a^n\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, A group can have an element of finite order and infinite order simultaneously..
For example the group of integers $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Here, order of $0$ is one. Where as all the other elements have infinite order.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb C^*$, the multiplicative group of the complex numbers.

Any element with norm $\neq 1$ has infinite order, but the group contains infinitely many roots of unity, solutions to $z^n=1$, hence infinitely many elements of finite order as well.

More broadly, you could always take direct products of groups to produce examples.  Thus, if $G_1$ is your favorite non-trivial finite group and $G_2$ is your favorite infinite group, then $G=G_1\times G_2$ has both elements of finite order and elements of infinite order.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $G=G_1\otimes G_2$...

Answer (score 0):

Completing the previous answers, you can get lots of (finitely generated) examples with [free products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product).

For instance, the [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group) is defined as $\langle a,b | a^2 =b^2 = 1 \rangle$ that is, elements are words other $a,b$ with no two consecutive $a$'s nor $b$'s, so in particular $a$ and $b$ are of order $2$ but $ab$ is of infinite order.

This group can be seen as the free product   $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$ of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and you could apply the same construction with any other group